# A script that can create a chess tree from an EPD file

Tags: software, programming, fen

Is there any script (any language) that can make a chess tree from an EPD file? Or what algorithm (any example) should be use to create it on my own?

I am looking for one like the Chessbase opening tree window. The EPD evalulation should be such that it is sorted by eval, but how I tell comp what position is first and what position is next one.

EDIT:
tree example
[image]

Comment: Is it possible to include an example of a chess tree in your question? Without knowing much about this, one idea could be to try to extract the necessary parts from the EPD (hopefully someone's written a python library that does that), and then convert that into a chess tree. But I am only speculating as I don't know either well

Comment: Hmmm. The inclusion of any sort of evaluation is not part of the standard EPD format (http://portablegamenotation.com/EPD.html) -- you may not find too many ready-made solutions for a proprietary extension of the standard. You could always try SCID (open source).

Answer (score 2):

Not exactly. Both Chess Position Trainer and Chess Openings Wizard (the successor of Bookup) can create a tree manually or importing a PGN, export the positions to EPD, and import the evaluations from EPD, but won't create positions from an EPD, so they can't create trees from EPD.

Answer (score 1):

I have seen two softwares that does what you wish. [Chess Position Trainer](http://www.chesspositiontrainer.com/) is one of them. The other is [bookup](http://www.bookup.com).

Those softwares reads games in pgn and files containing epd positions with its evaluations in centipawns.  This files contains the leaf nodes positions, generated by Chess Position Trainer for instance. You later analyze the epd file.

I use "GradualTest ver. 2.6" for this purpose. This program feeds the positions to an engine and writes the results to another file. I import the resulting file and the evaluations are added at the leaf positions. Later, the program propagates the valuations to the upstream positions, up to the root, applying the minimax algorithm.

Both programs are the best I have seen.